# Can't get model to be saved getting error: "TypeError expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to take info from a few models and generate table entries in the model Calendar. I cannot get it to save the Calendar entry. Getting a TypeError. Eventually I would like this system to add calendar entries into the future based of the last scheduled monday. But currently this task will only be performed on mondays. But I would like to be able to project more than one week forward if possible.

**Template:**

```
<form action="{% url 'portal:custom_admin' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div style="background-color:red; width:15%;">
        <button name="submit">Project</button>
        DANGER! Only click on mondays, until future projecter can go based off futuremost monday generated into Calendar
    </div>
</form>
```

**View with which I am struggling:**

```
def custom_admin(request):
"""
Displays MaxSettings, also
Takes time_slots and create a week of it into the future (only should be done on mondays)
Note:eventually this should be able to generate from the last monday in the calendar instead of today
"""
max_settings = MaxSettings.objects.filter()
time_slots = TimeSlots.objects.filter()

if request.method != 'POST':
    pass
    # Do nothing
else:
    # Project A week forward
    for slot in time_slots:
         #there will be an if statement for each weekday
        if slot.day.weekday == 'Monday':
            new_entry = Calendar(
                date=datetime.timedelta(days=7),
                timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                booked=False
            )
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal:custom_admin'))

calendar = Calendar.objects.filter()

context = {
    'max_settings': max_settings,
    'calendar': calendar,
}
return render(request, 'portal/custom_admin.html', context)
```

**Here are the relevant models:**

```
class MaxSettings(models.Model):
"""
Everyweek day has its own specified open/close time, time slots along with number of available jobs
"""
MONDAY = 'Monday'
TUESDAY = 'Tuesday'
WEDNESDAY = 'Wednesday'
THURSDAY = 'Thursday'
FRIDAY = 'Friday'
SATURDAY = 'Saturday'
SUNDAY = 'Sunday'
WEEKDAY_CHOICES = (
    (MONDAY, 'monday'),
    (TUESDAY, 'tuesday'),
    (WEDNESDAY, 'wednesday'),
    (THURSDAY, 'thursday'),
    (FRIDAY, 'friday'),
    (SATURDAY, 'saturday'),
    (SUNDAY, 'sunday'),
)
weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=WEEKDAY_CHOICES, )
operating = models.BooleanField()
start_work_time = models.TimeField()
end_work_time = models.TimeField()

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model."""
    return self.weekday


class TimeSlots(models.Model):
"""time slots along with number of available jobs for that slot"""
day = models.ForeignKey(MaxSettings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
timeslot_A = models.TimeField()
timeslot_B = models.TimeField()
max_jobs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model."""
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.timeslot_A, self.timeslot_B, self.day)


class Calendar(models.Model):
"""
this will get it details from TimeSlots and be generated into the future from the  MaxSettings
"""
date = models.DateField()
timeslot_A = models.TimeField()
timeslot_B = models.TimeField()
booked = models.BooleanField()
```

**Error Details:**

```
TypeError at /custom_admin/

expected string or bytes-like object

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom_admin/
 Django Version:    2.0
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value: expected string or bytes-like object

Exception Location:         error location: /site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py in parse_date, line 74
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon I stated "the view with which I am struggling" And in that view there is only one .save()... error location: /site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py in parse_date, line 74

Comment: @JohnGordon requested info added to question

Comment: So `new_entry = Calendar(...)` is successful, but `new_entry.save()` has the error?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes if i remove the line new_entry.save() and submit the form I get no errors.

Comment: Why are you passing `date=datetime.timedelta(days=7)` to the new `Calendar` object?  A `timedelta` is not a date.

Comment: @JohnGordon first I plan to only submit that form on mondays. So it takes todays date, and goes forward 7 days which brings it to next monday, and find that DateField, 7 days from now and sets the Calenders field day to that future date

Comment: A date plus a timedelta is a date, but a timedelta by itself is not a date.  I think that may be your problem.

Comment: `datetime.timedelta(days=7)` means "a period of seven days", which is meaningless without a starting date.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes that seems to be likely, if you don't mind.. How would I be able to do date plus a timedelta... I tried datetime.timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7), and get an error: type object 'datetime.timezone' has no attribute 'now'

Comment: `datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)`

Comment: @JohnGordon Ok that works now THANK YOU! Would you like to submit an answer to this question of how I can avoid doing this only on mondays and only projecting into the future one week? Say instead project into the future 12 weeks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the error happens because you're using a **datetime.timedelta** as a value for the **date** property of your **Calendar** entry. What [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) needs is a **datetime.date**.
To be more precise, Django needs a date (e.g.: "2018-01-17"), while you are only providing a difference between two dates (in your case: "7 days"). What your code should do is compute the date for the next Monday and then pass that value (cast as a datetime.date) to the **Calendar.date** property.

Comment: Thanks that is the issue. Would you like to explain how I can avoid doing this only on mondays and only projecting into the future one week? Say instead project into the future 12 weeks?

Comment: I will be brutally honest here: No I can not. In your original post you haven't described how you built your application, what you expect as inputs or how you plan on computing the date for your Calendars. Without any context, the best anyone can do is guess. Don't get me wrong I am willing to help, but I will need more information to work with.